# Array of object according to key and values javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, arraylist

I have a **array of object**  save data in an object according to its action_type key 
My Array Object data

```
var jsonData = [
{
        "id":"1000000",
        "action_type":"sms"
    },{
        "id":"1000001",
        "action_type":"push"  
    },{
        "id":"1000002",
        "action_type":"email"

    },{
        "id":"1000003",
        "action_type":"push"
    },{
        "id":"1000004",
        "action_type":"email"
    },{
        "id":"1000005",
        "action_type":"sms" 
    }
];
```

I want to store a data into multiple array of Objects on the basis of its action_type so that according to their type i perform action.

```
var ObjectSms  = [{"id":"1000000","action_type":"sms"},{"id":"1000005","action_type":"sms" }]; 

var ObjectPush = [{"id":"1000001","action_type":"push"},{"id":"1000003","action_type":"push" }];

var ObjectEmail = [{"id":"1000002","action_type":"email"},{"id":"1000004","action_type":"email" }];
```

so that according to its action type perform actions

```
if(action_type == "sms"){
  sendSmsFunction(ObjectSms);
}
if(action_type == "email"){
  sendEmailFunction(ObjectEmail);
}
if(action_type == "push"){
  sendPushFunction(ObjectPush);
}
```

Comment: Can u specify what is your problem?

Comment: This is **not a JSON**. This is an array of objects

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    var jsonData = [
    {
            "id":"1000000",
            "action_type":"sms"
        },{
            "id":"1000001",
            "action_type":"push"  
        },{
            "id":"1000002",
            "action_type":"email"

        },{
            "id":"1000003",
            "action_type":"push"
        },{
            "id":"1000004",
            "action_type":"email"
        },{
            "id":"1000005",
            "action_type":"sms" 
        }
    ];

    let smsArr = [];
    let emailArr = [];
    let pushArr = [];

    jsonData.forEach(obj => {
        if (obj.action_type === "sms") {
          smsArr.push(obj);
        }
        if (obj.action_type === "email") {
          emailArr.push(obj);
        }
        if (obj.action_type === "push") {
          pushArr.push(obj);
        }
    });
console.log(smsArr, emailArr, pushArr );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **destructuring assignment** and **reduce()** to achieve that result:

```js
var jsonData = [{
  "id": "1000000",
  "action_type": "sms"
}, {
  "id": "1000001",
  "action_type": "push"
}, {
  "id": "1000002",
  "action_type": "email"

}, {
  "id": "1000003",
  "action_type": "push"
}, {
  "id": "1000004",
  "action_type": "email"
}, {
  "id": "1000005",
  "action_type": "sms"
}];

const {
  ObjectSms,
  ObjectPush,
  ObjectEmail
} = jsonData.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (c.action_type === 'sms') {
    a.ObjectSms.push(c)
  } else if (c.action_type === 'push') {
    a.ObjectPush.push(c)
  } else if (c.action_type === 'email') {
    a.ObjectEmail.push(c)
  }
  return a
}, {
  ObjectSms: [],
  ObjectPush: [],
  ObjectEmail: []
})

console.log('ObjectSms', ObjectSms)
console.log('ObjectPush', ObjectPush)
console.log('ObjectEmail', ObjectEmail)
```

**Destructuring assignment:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

**Array.prototype.reduce():** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using [lodash](https://lodash.com/). using lodash filter function you can do this like:

```
var jsonData = [
{
    "id":"1000000",
    "action_type":"sms"
},{
    "id":"1000001",
    "action_type":"push"  
},{
    "id":"1000002",
    "action_type":"email"

},{
    "id":"1000003",
    "action_type":"push"
},{
    "id":"1000004",
    "action_type":"email"
},{
    "id":"1000005",
    "action_type":"sms" 
}];

const smsArr = [];
const emailArr = [];

_.filter(jsonData, d => {
    if(d.action_type == "sms"){
       smsArr.push(d)
    }
    else if (d.action_type == "email"){
        emailArr.push(d)
    }
})
```

Comment: If **lodash** then I think **.groupBy()** would be the fit function for this problem.